# Debug SimpleMembershipProvider source

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-debugging, simplemembership

I went through this article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx) which shows how one can debug asp.net source code.

Now, I'm having some serious trouble using the new `SimpleMembershipProvider` in `WebMatrix.WebData` namespace, and I want to debug it, but I'm not able to. When I try to step into the `WebSecurity.CreateAccount` method, it just steps over the method call.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Is WebMatrix.WebData a third party dll?  If so, you might need to decompile it, get the source and then add the source to your solution.  Otherwise I don't think you'll be able to set into it.

Comment: No, I don't think it is. The source code for this DLL is available at http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/, which is the official repository for asp.net. But you can't download debugging symbols from there (at least I did not find them).

Comment: Furthermore, it seems decompiling that assembly to include it in my solution is not an option, since it uses many internal methods scatered through the framework, which would required decompiling a series of DLLs. This would be messy...